# Accessing submatrices using LAPACK

Tags: c++, matrix, lapack

Is there a function in LAPACK, which will give me the elements of a particular submatrix? If so how what is the syntax in C++?

Or do I need to code it up?

Comment: Have a look at the [Armadillo C++ library](http://arma.sourceforge.net), which uses LAPACK and provides [submatrix views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat). For example, X.submat(4,5,9,10) = ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no function for accessing a submatrix.  However, because of the way matrix data is stored in LAPACK routines, you don't need one.  This saves a lot of copying, and the data layout was (partially) chosen for this reason:

Recall that a dense (i.e., not banded, triangular, hermitian, etc) matrix in LAPACK is defined by four values:

- a pointer to the top left corner of the matrix
- the number of rows in the matrix
- the number of columns in the matrix
- the "leading dimension" of the matrix; typically this is the distance in memory between adjacent elements of a row.

Most of the time, most people only ever use a leading dimension that is equal to the number of rows; a 3x3 matrix is typically stored like so:

```
a[0] a[3] a[6] 
a[1] a[4] a[7]
a[2] a[5] a[8]
```

Suppose instead that we wanted a 3x3 submatrix of a huge matrix with leading dimension `lda`.  Suppose we specifically want the 3x3 submatrix whose top-left corner is located at a(15,42):

```
         .             .            .
         .             .            .
... a[15+42*lda] a[15+43*lda] a[15+44*lda] ...
... a[16+42*lda] a[16+43*lda] a[16+44*lda] ...
... a[17+42*lda] a[17+43*lda] a[17+44*lda] ...
         .             .            .
         .             .            .
```

We *could* copy this 3x3 matrix into contiguous storage, but if we want to pass it as an input (or output) matrix to an LAPACK routine, we don't need to; we only need to define the parameters appropriately.  Let's call this submatrix `b`; we then define:

```
// pointer to the top-left corner of b:
float *b = &a[15 + 42*lda];
// number of rows in b:
const int nb = 3;
// number of columns in b:
const int mb = 3;
// leading dimension of b:
const int ldb = lda;
```

The only thing that might be surprising is the value of `ldb`; by using the value `lda` of the "big matrix", we can address the submatrix without copying, and operate on it in-place.

**However**
I lied (sort of).  Sometimes you really can't operate on a submatrix in place, and genuinely need to copy it.  I didn't want to talk about that, because it's rare, and you should use in-place operations whenever possible, but I would feel bad not telling you that it is possible.  The routine:

```
SLACPY(UPLO,M,N,A,LDA,B,LDB)
```

copies the `M`x`N` matrix whose top-left corner is `A` and is stored with leading dimension `LDA` to the `M`x`N` matrix whose top-left corner is `B` and has leading dimension `LDB`.  The `UPLO` parameter indicates whether to copy the upper triangle, lower triangle, or the whole matrix.

In the example I gave above, you would use it like this (assuming the clapack bindings):

```
...
const int m = 3;
const int n = 3;
float b[9];
const int ldb = 3;
slacpy("A",  // anything except "U" or "L" means "copy everything"
       &m,   // number of rows to copy
       &n,   // number of columns to copy
       &a[15 + 42*lda], // pointer to top-left element to copy
       lda,  // leading dimension of a (something huge)
       b,    // pointer to top-left element of destination
       ldb); // leading dimension of b (== m, so storage is dense)
...
```

Comment: great answer @Stephen; do you know if this approach to pass a submatrix can be easily generalized to passing a certain Minor of a matrix? say a 3x3 subminor containing only rows a,b,c and columns x,y,z

Comment: @lurscher: No, in general this does not suffice to pull out minors.  For that you need to do something more clever.

Comment: thanks to this amazing answer I finally understood what lda is for.

Comment: @FabianPedregosa: glad it was useful.  It took me a long time to fully appreciate how powerful this scheme is, too.

Comment: Great answer. @StephenCanon My problem differs slightly in that given an MxN matrix I want the submatrix Mxn, with n<N, formed by removing some of the columns of the original matrix. I have to do this at every iteration for many iterations. The obvious thing to do would be to copy these columns into a new matrix but I would like to avoid the copying at each iteration. Is there anything smart and elegant I can do?

Comment: @StephenCanon, how to multiply two submatrices when we have [0/1] indices for row and columns of matrix, so the submatrix may not be contiguous in memory?