# Accessing submatrices using cuBLAS

Tags: matrix, cuda, fortran, partitioning, cublas

I have read the following post

[Accessing submatrices using LAPACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009513/accessing-submatrices-using-lapack)

I would like to do something similar calling cuBLAS routines from Fortran.

Basically I have a large matrix partitioned into `3 x 3` blocks with the partitioning changing in each step of a loop. At the moment, I allocate/free pointers for each individual sub-block and copy the relevant parts of the matrix to and from the device at each step. That creates a lot of overhead which I am hoping to eliminate. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do device pointer arithmetic in host code in just the same way as you would with host pointers. For example, if you had an MxN matrix stored on the GPU:

```
 float *A_d;
 cudaMalloc((void **)&A_d, size_t(M*N)*sizeof(float));
```

and you wanted to operate on a submatrix starting at (x1,y1), then you would pass `A+x1+M*y1`  to any CUBLAS function which expects a matrix as an argument.

Comment: that sounds simple - in fortran, the pointer is an integer(8) variable (don't know why, just followed examples) - can I just add to it in the same way?

Comment: In CUDA, the pointer is always the same size as the host poiter. So if your OS is 64 bit, it should be OK. I haven't tried CUBLAS with Fortran host code for about three or four years, so I am not sure whether there are any vestigial gotchas to worry about. But certainly is C++ host code, that is how it works,

Answer (score 4):

talonmies has already satisfactorily answered this question. To support his answer and to be possibly useful to other users, I'm here providing a full example on how using `cublas<t>gemm` to perform multiplications between submatrices of full matrices `A` and `B` and how assigning the result to a submatrix of a full matrix `C`.

Although the question regards Fortran, the code below is given in C/C++ since I'm not using Fortran in connection with CUDA and since many users are using CUDA in connection with C/C++.

The code makes use of

1. pointer arithmetics to access submatrices;
2. the concept of the leading dimension and of submatrix dimensions.

The code below considers three matrices:

1. `A` - `10 x 9`;
2. `B` - `15 x 13`;
3. `C` - `10 x 12`.

Matrix `C` is initialized to all `10`s. The code performs the following submatrix multiplication in Matlab language:

```
C(1+x3:5+x3,1+y3:3+y3) = A(1+x1:5+x1,1+y1:4+y1) * B(1+x2:4+x2,1+y2:3+x2);
```

The `Utilities.cu` and `Utilities.cuh` files are mantained [here](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA_Utilities) and omitted here.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>

#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    /**************************/
    /* SETTING UP THE PROBLEM */
    /**************************/

    //const int Nrows1 = 10;            // --- Number of rows of matrix 1
    //const int Ncols1 = 10;            // --- Number of columns of matrix 1

    //const int Nrows2 = 15;            // --- Number of rows of matrix 2
    //const int Ncols2 = 15;            // --- Number of columns of matrix 2

    //const int Nrows3 = 12;            // --- Number of rows of matrix 3
    //const int Ncols3 = 12;            // --- Number of columns of matrix 3

    const int Nrows1 = 10;          // --- Number of rows of matrix 1
    const int Ncols1 = 9;           // --- Number of columns of matrix 1

    const int Nrows2 = 15;          // --- Number of rows of matrix 2
    const int Ncols2 = 13;          // --- Number of columns of matrix 2

    const int Nrows3 = 10;          // --- Number of rows of matrix 3
    const int Ncols3 = 12;          // --- Number of columns of matrix 3

    const int Nrows = 5;            // --- Number of rows of submatrix matrix 3 = Number of rows of submatrix 1
    const int Ncols = 3;            // --- Number of columns of submatrix matrix 3 = Number of columns of submatrix 2

    const int Nrowscols = 4;        // --- Number of columns of submatrix 1 and of rows of submatrix 2

    const int x1 = 3;               // --- Offset for submatrix multiplication along the rows
    const int y1 = 2;               // --- Offset for submatrix multiplication along the columns

    const int x2 = 6;               // --- Offset for submatrix multiplication along the rows
    const int y2 = 4;               // --- Offset for submatrix multiplication along the columns

    const int x3 = 3;               // --- Offset for submatrix multiplication along the rows
    const int y3 = 5;               // --- Offset for submatrix multiplication along the columns

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 0 and 100
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 20);

    // --- Matrix allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_matrix1(Nrows1 * Ncols1);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_matrix2(Nrows2 * Ncols2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_matrix1.size(); i++) d_matrix1[i] = (float)dist(rng);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_matrix2.size(); i++) d_matrix2[i] = (float)dist(rng);

    printf("\n\nOriginal full size matrix A\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows1; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols1; j++) 
            std::cout << d_matrix1[j * Nrows1 + i] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    printf("\n\nOriginal full size matrix B\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows2; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols2; j++) 
            std::cout << d_matrix2[j * Nrows2 + i] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    /*************************/
    /* MATRIX MULTIPLICATION */
    /*************************/
    cublasHandle_t handle;

    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&handle));

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_matrix3(Nrows3 * Ncols3, 10.f);

    float alpha = 1.f;
    float beta  = 0.f;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, Nrows, Ncols, Nrowscols, &alpha,
                   thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix1.data())+x1+Nrows1*y1, Nrows1, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix2.data())+x2+Nrows2*y2, Nrows2,
                   &beta, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix3.data())+x3+Nrows3*y3, Nrows3));

    printf("\n\nResult full size matrix C\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows3; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols3; j++) 
            std::cout << d_matrix3[j * Nrows3 + i] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    return 0; 
}
```